# How to train LSTM model on multiple time series data each having different timesteps?

Tags: keras, time-series, lstm

How to train LSTM model on multiple time series data where each time series has different timesteps/lags.

Use case: I have daily transactions(WIthdrawals) of 100 ATMS for last 5 years. Need to forecast next withdrawals based on timesteps for each ATM.

1. How to use embedding(latent representation for each ATM ID) if I pass ATM ID as feature and train on all data at once
2. How to pass all time series data to LSTM at once, how LSTM will distinguish one time series from another?